# Can anyone give me a lead on the Lando Calrissian Robe lining

Tags: star-wars, costume

[image]

Looking to do a Lando cosplay and need to find the lining.  I've searched everywhere and can't find the right fabric.

Comment: That looks like a paisely pattern. Wouldn't surprise me if it started out as a furniture covering.

Comment: Ah, and indeed, [this fellow](https://blackthreads.wordpress.com/tag/lando-calrissian/) used paisley fabric, although they noted the original was probably silk brocade.

Comment: https://www.etsy.com/listing/780389017/light-gold-color-brocade-fabric-with lacks some of the darker bits, but otherwise looks close.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - That link doesn't work

Comment: I've taken the liberty of posting a better quality photo that shows the stylised dragons in the pattern.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I've found a bunch of semi-identical patterns like this on brocade. It looks like a fairly common pattern used in cheap imported oriental fabric. Tracking down the original would be quite difficult as I suspect it was just bought as a bolt of fabric

Comment: It's worth noting that the darker inside is just the obverse of the outside. I'm not sure, but I think this is a result of the way the cloth is made; so if you can find the outside pattern then you likely have the inside too.

Comment: @bob1 - if you look near the collars, you'll see that the gold brocade is only loosely stitched to the outside material. If it was *manufactured* that way, the stitching would be much tighter. Prop clothing is often impractical as real clothing or would fall apart from real wear.

Answer (score 34):

[This company](http://asian-culture-shop.com/Chinese_Traditional_Dragons_Pattern_Design_Beige_Brocade_Fabric_Asian_Silk_Fabric_Chinese_Fabric_Material-170741-) Has a nearly identical pattern, with a gold background, orange dragons and darker coloured vines.  It looks like a fairly common pattern used in cheap imported oriental fabric.

[image]
<sub><sup>*"Chinese Traditional Dragons Pattern Design Beige Brocade Fabric Asian Silk Fabric Chinese Fabric Material"*</sup></sub>

Comment: looks exactly the same if you artificially age it a bit

Comment: @Hobbamok - I'm not 101% happy with this one. The dragon looks a bit orange and the leaves a bit dark. They also do a bronze version where the leaves are lighter but the dragon is yellow not orange. If I was aiming for perfection, I'd buy this one and put it on a series of hot washes to leach out some of the dye.

Comment: is the photo from OP from the time period or 40+ years later? That time may account for the fading and the replica is a period accurate representation?

Comment: @NKCampbell - I did consider that. Contemporary photos show that the colours are much the same and haven't faded;  https://images.app.goo.gl/uBtf7Z1UwsvV3o4o8